# Date is coming differently in local and live environments in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have date like `"9999-12-30 18:30:00+00"` in database.

When i am accessing from local machine it is coming as `9999-12-31 00:00:00.0`(In India)
When i am accessing from live it is coming as `9999-12-30 00:00:00.0`(In US)

data type is `timestamp with time zone`

What might be the wrong.Thanks in advance...

The following code i am using to save the date

```c
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Date date = formatter.parse("12/31/9999");

SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

String formattedDate = formatter1.format(date);
//formatter1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Date finalDate = formatter1.parse(formattedDate);

System.out.println(finalDate);
```

It is saving as `"9999-12-30 18:30:00+00"`

Comment: Yes, everything is correct because you have `+00` time zone defined in your db. So it is time zone dependent.

Comment: @AlexStybaev What i need to do now to get the same in both places

Comment: Please, provide your code snippet which you use to load data from DB, so I could tell you how to improve it.

Comment: i am using java and hibernate

Comment: What exactly means _from local_  and _from live_ ?

Comment: local means from devolopement machine and live means which is located at some other location.But from both places i connected to same database.

Comment: Please, tell us what goal you are trying to achieve

Comment: The java.util.Date doesnot contain any timeZone information. When you print a java.util.Date, it is formatted with the local JVM's default timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `timestamp with time zone` (as opposed to its counterpart `timestamp without time zone`) is that the value is dynamically rotated depending on the timezone of the client running the query.

Since you insist that you're connected to the same database, as if it would imply that both clients should retrieve the same value, maybe you don't understand that it's normal that they retrieve different values.

To illustrate, here's a reproducible example with your values:

```
create table ttz(t timestamptz);
insert into ttz values('9999-12-30 18:30:00+00');
```

- When my timezone is the default 'localtime' which is in fact 'Europe/Paris', which at this future date if our world still exists, is supposed to be one hour ahead of UTC, here's what I get:

> ```
> => select * from ttz;
>            t            
> ------------------------
>  9999-12-30 19:30:00+01
> ```

- Now let's switch to a timezone in India:

> ```
> => set timezone to 'Asia/Calcutta';
> => select * from ttz;
>              t             
> ---------------------------
>  9999-12-31 00:00:00+05:30
> ```

So if I pretend to be in India, it outputs the same value than your session in India. This is the expected result.

- About the result in the US

US has several time zones so you should first check which one is used by your server.
The strange thing is that in order to get your result of `9999-12-30 00:00:00` from the UTC `9999-12-30 18:30`, you'd need to have an offset of +18:30 that doesn't exist in practice although it would coincide with India if going west instead of east from UTC.

> ```
> => set timezone to 'UTC+18:30';
> => select * from ttz ;
>              t             
> ---------------------------
>  9999-12-30 00:00:00-18:30
> (1 row)
> ```

Thus it can be suspected that your client session in US just has a badly configured timezone.

See also [PostgreSQL 9.1 timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140082/postgresql-9-1-timezones) for the problem of conflicting sign conventions when using offsets from UTC.

Comment: Thank u so much.You are right.Actually i got the problem when i inserted the record from and retrieve from the live server(Because database for both are same).I understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that both your local and live databases are using proper time on server side - both should be using NTP to synchronize server time.

If you use proper datetime format of [Z or X](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it will keep timezone information present in your printed timestamp (but it may look textually different for local and live db).

If you don't want to keep this info or not willing to change your format, you can use `AT TIME ZONE` syntax when retrieving your datetime such that you always get it at some predetermined time zone, say `UTC`:

```
SELECT dt AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM mytable
```

For time zone here you can use usual syntax like `'+00'` (same as `'UTC'`), `'+08'`, etc.

Comment: i am accessing the same database from local which is located at US

Comment: I would be very surprised if querying `AT TIME ZONE ...` by different clients but from the same database gave you different result.

Comment: I am also unable to understand this problem